# Select option tag with "Please select" message

Tags: html

I want a dropdown list with say the following options and to show please select when no option is selected. I have implemented it with the code below and the form is submitted when an option is selected as expected.

The problem is when I navigate back to the page, and select the first option i.e `--Please Select--`, my form gets submitted for that option too. Is there any way to display a `--Please Select--` option when no option is selected and prevent the form from being submitted for that particular `--Please Select--` option?

```
<select onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option>--Please Select--</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You don't have any error trapping to make sure a select value has been selected ?

Comment: You could add a check to see which option was selected … but just replace the whole thing with regular links.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `<option selected="selected" disabled="true">`

Selected means it will be default, and then disabled stops it being clicked on.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u8PWX/1/)

```
<select onchange="this.form.submit()">
  <option selected="selected" disabled="true">--Please Select --</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the "Please Select" option disabled. This way the option will be initially selected but it can't be selected again.

```
<select onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option disabled="true">--Please Select --</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:)

```
<select onchange="if(this.value!='') this.form.submit();">
    <option value="">--Please Select --</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do it in javascript.

```
<select onchange="if (this.selectedIndex !=0) { this.form.submit(); }">
    <option>--Please Select --</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

since this is a php you're probably dynamically generating your select options so you might need to change the code a bit.